# How to sort an array of objects depending on a custom sort order using underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I have an array of objects

```
[
  {type:"foo",elements:[...]},
  {type:"bar",elements:[...]},
  {type:"any",[...]},
  {type:"some",elements:[...]}
]
```

I know how to sort that array by the attribute 'type' using underscore's _.sortBy() method.

But now I need a custom sort order which depends on another array:

```
["any","foo","some","bar"]
```

How would my sortBy callback have to look like to sort my objects by my custom order?

Comment: how does your custom order depend on the array ? Is your array an already sorted list of types ?

Comment: @VonD the reference is a user depended sort order of available types

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's easy:

```
_.sortBy(yourArrray, function(obj){
   return typesArray.indexOf(obj.type);
});
```

It sorts `yourArray` based on position of `obj.type` in `typesArray`. Types not present in array comes first.

Beware - this code have complexity `O(kn log n)`. To improve it, use following code:

```
var yourTypes = {
   'any': 1,
   'foo': 2,
    'some': 3
}
_.sortBy(yourArrray, function(obj){
   return yourTypes [obj.type];
});
```

Object lookups are usually faster, resulting in O(1) access (and overall O(n log n) sorting).

Comment: perfect answer. We will have only 10 different types, so it shouldn't matter performance wise - but thanks for the additional important information!